# Use javascript to launch local file on user's machine?

Tags: javascript, vba

I have an Excel macro that runs in a workbook that our company uses.  I've made cells look like hyperlinks, so when someone double-clicks on the link it opens IBM mainframe and loads up some data.  I'm writing another app for us that's web based, and I'm wondering if this same functionality is possible.  I haven't seen anything on the internet that would lead me to believe I could do this, but I thought I'd ask anyway....

```
Public SODD         As String

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Target.Column = 2 And (Target.Row >= 1) Then
    SODD = Target.Value
    Call SOLookup
End If
End Sub


Sub SOLookup()

Dim autECLPS                                            As Object
Dim s                                                   As New AutSess


AppActivate "3270 Terminal"
s.SetConnectionByName ("A")
s.autECLPS.StartCommunication
s.autECLPS.SendKeys "[Clear]"
s.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady (500)
s.autECLPS.SetText "SODD " & SODD
s.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady (500)
s.autECLPS.SendKeys "[ENTER]"
s.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady (500)


End Sub
```

This loads the IBM mainframe and types in the sales order number into their screen and hits Enter.

Would I be able to accomplish this same feat using something like Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript may not execute files on the user's local environment.  However, a server side language may do what you require.  For instance, you can use AJAX(javascript) to make a call to a PHP script which can execute, say, a batch file (.bat) which can then run your macro. The PHP file *could* have code as simple as

```
system("cmd /c C:[path to your macro/.bat file]");
```

Again, this all depends on your configuration and environment. So to recap: Web Browser->AJAX->PHP->Macro.

Comment: yup, this is exactly what i was looking for.  I can definitely write an AJAX script to accomplish this.  Thank you!

Comment: Note however that PHP runs on the server, so that script needs to be there. If you want to work with data on the user's computer, you have to upload it first.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Javascript nor any other script that runs inside the browser is allowed to execute any file locally on a user's computer. And this is a good tihng. Imagine what would happen if any website could randomly execute programs on your computer...

Internet ressources are not trusted, therefore they are not allowed to do anything on your local computer.

If the website is running in your company's intranet, there might be a way using proprietary MS technology and the Internet Explorer with properly configured trusted sites - but I wouldn't bother with it.